# C# detect when form becomes unfocused?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

Is there a winforms event that fires when the user switches from a form to another window? I.e. Not through minimizing, but just by clicking on another window. How can I detect when the form becomes inactive? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Form.Deactivate

Comment: Yeah, I just found out. Thanks!